# How to access template value parameter from a debugging helper in Qt Creator?

Tags: python, c++, qt-creator

I have a class, something like

```
class FixedPoint<int frac> {
    ...
    private:
        std::uint32_t value;
}
```

I want to write a debugging helper that represents a FixedPoint value as a floating-point number. I could do that if I knew the frac value. Is there a way to access it?

For now I consider parsing `value.dynamicTypeName()` which seems to contain the full template name including the parameters, but it feels hacky...

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: there are methods to access value template parameters. In my case you do it like this:

```
def qdump__FixedPoint(d, value):
    frac = int(value.type.template_argument(0))
    d.putValue(value['value'] / float(1 << frac))
```

[Source](https://qt.developpez.com/doc/qtcreator-2.3/creator-debugging-helpers/).